# Bad text rendering using DrawString on top of transparent pixels

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing, drawstring

When rendering text into a bitmap, I find that text looks very bad when rendered on top of an area with non-opaque alpha. The problem is progressively worse as the underlying pixels become more transparent. If I had to guess I'd say that when underlying pixels are transparent, the text renderer draws any anti-aliased 'gray' pixels as solid black.

Here are some screenshots:

**Text drawn on top of transparent pixels:**

[image]

**Text drawn on top of semi-transparent pixels:**

[image]

**Text drawn on opaque pixels:**

[image]

Here is the code used to render the text:

```
g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
g.DrawString("Press the spacebar", Font, Brushes.Black, textLeft, textTop);
```

Comment: I believe the result will also depend if ClearType is enabled or not.

Comment: Looks you are not 'clearing' (or rather invalidating) the transparent background.

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Comment: Are you able to upload the images you included to Stack Overflow? They're not coming down from Dropbox anymore.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The option I used to workaround this problem was:

```
Graphics graphics = new Graphics();
graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit;
```

There are some others useful options in TextRenderingHint

Hope it helps

Comment: Swapped answer for this one, although this is a very old question and I've not tested this answer.

Comment: user3470185's answer (g.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit) produces better result.

Comment: That works for the control I'm modding (But I used `TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit` just to fix the default bad hinting applied to that control text)

Answer (score 22):

There is a very simple answer to this...

```
g.TextRenderingHint = Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit
```

If you set this before you render your text, it will come out clear. In addition, this methods supports more font sizes (The default only goes up to size 56).

Thanks for reading this post.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is beautiful!

Answer (score 14):

The first output is what you get when you draw black text on a black background, probably Color.Transparent.  The 2nd was drawn on an almost-black background.  The 3rd was drawn on the same background it is being displayed with.

Anti-aliasing cannot work when on a transparent background.  The colors used for the anti-aliasing pixels will not blend the letter shape into the background when the text is displayed with a different background.  Those pixels will now become *very* noticeable and make the text look very bad.

Note that SmoothingMode doesn't affect text output.  It will look slightly less bad if you use a lower quality TextRenderingHint and a background color that's grayish with a alpha of zero.  Only TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit avoids all anti-aliasing troubles.

Getting a perfect fix for this is very difficult.  Vista's glass effect on the window title bar uses very subtle shading to give the text a well defined background color.  You'd need SysInternals' ZoomIt tool to really see it.  DrawThemeTextEx() function with a non-zero iGlowSize.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something that preserves antialiasing a bit better than GDI+ does by default, you can call `Graphics.Clear` with a chroma key, then manually remove the chroma artifacts that result.  (See *[Why does DrawString look so crappy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892270/why-does-drawstring-look-so-crappy)* and *[Ugly looking text problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167937/ugly-looking-text-problem)*.)

Here's how I ultimately ended up solving a similar problem:

```
static Bitmap TextToBitmap(string text, Font font, Color foregroundColor)
{
  SizeF textSize;

  using ( var g = Graphics.FromHwndInternal(IntPtr.Zero) )
    textSize = g.MeasureString(text, font);

  var image = new Bitmap((int)Math.Ceiling(textSize.Width), (int)Math.Ceiling(textSize.Height));
  var brush = new SolidBrush(foregroundColor);

  using ( var g = Graphics.FromImage(image) )
  {
    g.Clear(Color.Magenta);
    g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.DrawString(text, font, brush, 0, 0);
    g.Flush();
  }

  image.MakeTransparent(Color.Magenta);

  // The image now has a transparent background, but around each letter are antialiasing artifacts still keyed to magenta.  We need to remove those.
  RemoveChroma(image, foregroundColor, Color.Magenta);
  return image;
}

static unsafe void RemoveChroma(Bitmap image, Color foregroundColor, Color chroma)
{
  if (image == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("image");
  BitmapData data = null;

  try
  {
    data = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    for ( int y = data.Height - 1; y >= 0; --y )
    {
      int* row = (int*)(data.Scan0 + (y * data.Stride));
      for ( int x = data.Width - 1; x >= 0; --x )
      {
        if ( row[x] == 0 ) continue;
        Color pixel = Color.FromArgb(row[x]);

        if ( (pixel != foregroundColor) &&
             ((pixel.B >= foregroundColor.B) && (pixel.B <= chroma.B)) &&
             ((pixel.G >= foregroundColor.G) && (pixel.G <= chroma.G)) &&
             ((pixel.R >= foregroundColor.R) && (pixel.R <= chroma.R)) )
        {
          row[x] = Color.FromArgb(
            255 - ((int)
              ((Math.Abs(pixel.B - foregroundColor.B) +
                Math.Abs(pixel.G - foregroundColor.G) +
                Math.Abs(pixel.R - foregroundColor.R)) / 3)),
            foregroundColor).ToArgb();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    if (data != null) image.UnlockBits(data);
  }
}
```

It's a shame GDI/GDI+ doesn't do this already, but that would be sensible, wouldn't it?  :)

If you aren't able to use an `unsafe` context, you could easily use the same logic with `Bitmap.GetPixel` and `Bitmap.SetPixel`, though it will be significantly slower.