# Graphics.DrawString doesn't draw last SPACE chars?

Tags: c#, drawstring

The string is "Hello World          " with 10 SPACE chars in the end, but Graphics.DrawString in **Right Alignment** omits all of SPACE chars, it just draws "Hello World" only.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {            
        Rectangle rct = new Rectangle(20, 100, 200, 20);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Lime), rct);            
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello World          ", Font, new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText), rct, new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far});                                                      

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The flag works. You save me many hours. Can you do me a favor to make this as an Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the *Trailing Spaces* when drawing strings with Gdi+ [`Graphics.DrawString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) method, pass a [`StringFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) to a proper overload and add or append (`|=`) the [`StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformatflags?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) value to the [`StringFormat.FormatFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.formatflags?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) property.

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Rectangle rct = new Rectangle(20, 100, 200, 20);
    string s = "Hello World          ";

    using (var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic))
    {
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;

        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(s, Font, SystemBrushes.ControlText, rct, sf);
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Lime, rct);
}
```

Consider using the Gdi [`TextRenderer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) class to draw strings over controls unless you encounter problems like [drawing on transparent backgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70242614/14171304).

The previous code could have been written like:

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    Rectangle rct = new Rectangle(20, 100, 200, 20);
    string s = "Hello World          ";

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, s, Font, rct, SystemColors.ControlText,
        TextFormatFlags.Right |
        TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Lime, rct);
}
```

Comment: Though this answer, I not only resolved my particular problem but also learned proper coding style. I have being confused by MS doc about StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces in English. If the doc said "... the trailing SPACE chars at the end of ..." then I could understand better.