# C# Transparency text blending

Tags: c#

I'm using Forms to create a transparent window with:

`Designer.cs`

```
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
this.TransparencyKey = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;
```

and in the window, I have a label with some text.

```
this.label1.Text = "Hello      world!";
```

when the text is rendered, it blends with the background to create a smoothing effect. However when the background is removed, the blending stays and messes up the text, as show here:
[image]

The "Hello" is over the original background color so the blending is fine, but the "world" is over a different color, but the label is still blending with the original background color.

How can this blending effect be removed? Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70242614/14171304